# FormMethod.Post didn´t work with not default action. Razor and MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I´m new in MVC with Razor... I´m trying to do a login page, so i have this code in my cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.usuario)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.usuario)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.password)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.rememberMe)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.rememberMe)

    <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión" />                   
}
```

In the controller i have this:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{       
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(Login lg)
    {
        if(//valido mi usuario)
        { 
            return RedirectToAction("MyContent", "MyContent");
        }

        return View("Login");
    }
 }
```

But it never called the action "LogOn" it only called the action default "Login" and i don´t know which is the error...

Pleas help me!!!

Thanks!

Comment: It really, really should be calling that action.  How specifically have you confirmed that it isn't?

Comment: I think it is hitting the `If` condition and that expression is return false and you are seeing the login view because you have a `return View("Login")`

Comment: I put a breakpoint before de "if( )", the breakpoint is where i was declaring and assining some variables. And it never called.

Comment: And when i clicked the submit button it called the first action "Login()"

Comment: Someone knows anything? I Read other post, and it saids that the problem is for other Views and Models, but i dont know how did it afect??

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was my web config authentication was incorrect and i didn´t do models for all my other Views, so this was the problem...

When i deleted the authentication section for the web config it works...

Thanks!!!